# Evince is not refreshing

Tags: pdf, latex, pdf-reader, evince, pdflatex

To clarify I think at one point when you edited a PDF say by compiling with `pdflatex`, the edits appear immediately in Evince reader and didn't require you to close the viewer and open it to see the edits, how do I get it do this again?

Also is there a refreshing PDF reader for Windows?

Just to clarify I'm compiling a PDF using TexMaker and want the edits to show immediately in Evince reader, rather than having to close and reopen Evince to see the edits.

1. I am editing a PDF file with LaTeX
2. I am seeing that when the PDF file updates Evince does not show this change in the editor
3. I would like (and my understanding is) that when a PDF is edited using say MikTeX that without closing Evince the editor automatically shows the changed PDF rather than the original one that you opened similar to Preview.app in macOS

Yes I posted this before here: [Evince (pdf reader) is not refreshing in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1381125/evince-pdf-reader-is-not-refreshing-in-windows?noredirect=1#comment2090848_1381125)
I tried addressing the points given, have had no response.
If system information is needed,  I'm using Windows 10 64-bit Asus PC 
Please don't close my question.
An alternative refreshing (the way Preview.app does on macOS) PDF reader  is also good.

Answer (score 0):

1. One auto-refreshing PDF viewer for Windows is **[SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/manual.html)**.
2. Evince may not be auto-refreshing as expected, because this function depends on a working `inotify`.

   - Your number of current `inotify` watches may have exceeded its default limit, which on most Linux is defined as 10.000.
   - In order to extend the default limit to 100.000, first run this command to see if it helps:

     ```
     sudo sysctl -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000
     ```

     If it helps, make this extended limit survive the next reboot of your system and put it into */etc/sysctl.conf* by running these two commands:

     ```
     echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 \
        | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf

     sudo sysctl -p
     ```

Comment: is this fine to do on windows? I probably should have specified I use windows

Comment: @HaoSun: No, this will not work on Windows. Sorry; I assumed you use Linux when I wrote my (now stupid) answer. I must have forgotten that you explicitly and clearly had stated your operating system. My bad! -- So only my point "1." may still be relevant to you....

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, simply restarting evince may fix it. It sometimes stops auto-refreshing after the PDF (or the directory containing it) gets deleted and then restored.